# Convert a date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I need to convert the string date format from 
**Fri Feb 20 11:13:43 GMT 2015** to 
**2015/20/02 11:12**

I used

```
var dateTest = new Date("Fri Feb 20 11:13:43 GMT 2015");
var yr = dateTest.getYear();
```

but yr seems to return **"115"**

Comment: One good thing to do when something acts as you don't expect - [review the documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=&topic=js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var yr = DateTest.getFullYear();
```

Comment: this is right but it returns 1 for getMonth(), 5 for getDay()

Comment: For month increment it by one and use getDate() instead of getDay(). getDay() will return day of week.

Comment: @MelSyGallosa As expected, `getMonth()` returns the 0-based month and `getDay()` returns the 0-based day of week - review [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: thank you! to get the format that I wanted. I used

dateTest.getFullYear() + "/" + dateTest.getMonth()+1 + "/" + dateTest.getDate + " " + dateTest.getUTCHours() + ":" +dateTest.getUTCMinutes()

Answer (score 1):

You want to use

```
var yr = dateTest.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Its Return full date and you can also change its format as you want

**For Return Year**

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getFullYear());
```

**Return Full Date**

```
  var d = new Date();

  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();

  var output = (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' +
  (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
  d.getFullYear();

  alert(output);
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sckwzxxr/1/)